# Browser back button with divs hidden with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I have a website where real estate properties search results are displayed like using `<div>`s with just 6 displayed by default and "load more" button. When user clicks Load more button, 9 more posts displayed, etc. How it is done: `div`s are hidden by default (`display: none;`) and then `.show` class is added to the next 9 items.

```
a("span.more-search-items").on("click", function(t) {
    t.preventDefault();
    var e = a(this).parents(".property-search");
    e.find(".prop").not(".show").slice(0, 9).each(function() {
        var t = a(this).attr("data-img");
        a(this).css("background-image", "url(" + t + ")"), a(this).find(".main-image").attr("src", t), a(this).addClass("show")
    }), 0 == e.find(".prop").not(".show").length && a("span.more-search-items").hide();
    e.find(".prop.show").length
```

When user goes to single property and then hits back browser button, it shows the first 6 items again. I tried to implement `history.pushState()` method there where URL changes for each "load more" button click:

```
var href = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
var currentPage = location.hash.replace("#","");
history.pushState(null, null, href + "#" + (+currentPage + 1));
```

URL changes but the story is still the same - only first 6 results are being displayed when user goes back in history. Is there something I can do in this situation?

Comment: so you load all the divs onload and use `Load more` to just show them?

Comment: yes, then lazy-load images only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to deal with `History API` you need

- on load more click you need to push or replace the history with something like the numbers of visible divs with hash `#15 , #24` something like this
- With push/replace state you need to use `$(window).on('popstate' , function(){ alert(window.location.hash); })` and while *user goes to single property* it refresh all the page and when browser back button clicked it returns and refreshes the previous page .. so you need to check `alert(window.location.hash);` when page load

Finally when you got an alert with the number from `window.location.hash` you can then show the divs depending on it

Ok let me explain this for you in code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    alert(window.location.hash); // check the alert here

    $('.load_more_button').on('click' , function(){
        if(window.location.hash){
           var href = window.location.href.split('#');
           var currentPage = parseInt(window.location.hash);
           history.pushState(null, null, href[0] + "#" + (+currentPage + 1));
        }
    });
    $(window).on('popstate' , function(){
        alert(window.location.hash);  // check the alert here
    });
});
```

You can start from here when you get the number do as you like

Comment: thanks for the approach, it worked. I didn't use `popstate` in the end but count `(".prop.show").length`, update hash in URL with `history.pushState` accordingly, then add CSS classes to posts based on hash on window load.